# How do I build an Xcode shortcut for frequently used code snippet?

Tags: xcode, code-snippets

I have a Debug statement that I use quite often that I would like to build a Xcode shortcut for so I don't have to type it in all the time, how is it possible to make a shortcut that inserts a code snippet as below?

```
 if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
        NSLog(@"---- CHANGE THIS ----", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
 }
```

Comment: Try [this](http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/).

Comment: http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/

Comment: TIL there is snippets.

Comment: worked great please provide and answer and I will accept it